# How to push elements and save them in the array in pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, list, arraylist, element

Messed up with a basics.

As I press the enter key or click the button, `list` array's element is changed, not appended the new element I wrote.

Also, I would like to `reset` for `<input type='text' maxlength='8' id='aName' placeholder='Write a name.' onKeyDown='enterkey();' />`, but have no clue to do.

How can I amend the code below?

```js
function enterkey() {
  if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
    pushingName();
  }
}

function pushingName(){
  var list=[];
  var oneName = document.getElementById('aName').value;
  var stringName = oneName.toString();

  var nameList = list.push(stringName);

  console.log(list);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' maxlength='8' id='aName' placeholder='Write a name.' onKeyDown='enterkey();' />
<button onclick='pushingName();'>ADD</button>
```

Comment: @CalvinNunes Thanks. and how can I reset input value?

Comment: I deleted my first comment and since I saw other things that I think is relevant to you (I presume you are learning), I added an answer below, take a look, if it is useful for you, upvote and accept, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this updated snippet below.

in addition if you need it, it also:

1. cuts spaces at the beginning and end so `' ss  '` => `'ss'`
2. does nothing when string is empty
3. avoiding duplicates in a array
4. resets input value after it was added. (not resets in cas of attempting to addd a dupicate)
5. removes using another button

```js
let list = [];


function enterkey() {
  if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
    pushingName();
  }
}

function pushingName(){

  var elName = document.getElementById('aName');
  var stringName = elName.value.toString();
  
  // trimming string if you need it
  stringName = stringName.trim();
  
  if (!stringName.length) {
    return; // check ot mpty string if you need it
  }

  if (list.indexOf(stringName) === -1) { // avoid duplications if you need it
    var nameList = list.push(stringName);
    
    elName.value = ''; // reset value to empty if was added
  }
  
  console.log(list);
}

function removeName(){

  var oneName = document.getElementById('aName').value;
  var stringName = oneName.toString();
  
  // trimming string if you need it
  stringName = stringName.trim();
  
  if (!stringName.length) {
    return; // check ot mpty string if you need it
  }

  // filtering our stringName
  list = list.filter(item => item !== stringName);

  
  console.log(list);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' maxlength='8' id='aName' placeholder='Write a name.' onKeyDown='enterkey();' />
<button onclick='pushingName();'>ADD</button>
<button onclick='removeName();'>REMOVE</button>
```